# Counting no of vehicles java

Tags: java, count

This is part of my code for a car park system. I am having some problems with using 'count'. Currently, my program adds 1 to the count for every input 'reg no', 'high value' and 'large vehicle'. I want my program to just add 1 every time i enter a new vehicle registration number only? How do I do this? I am not very good with counting in Java. Here is what I have so far:

```
package carpark;


import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class textBox extends javax.swing.JFrame 
implements ActionListener 
  { // declare the components and variables 
  private final JLabel inputLabel,inputLabel2,inputLabel3,countLabel; 
  private final JTextField inputBox,inputBox2,inputBox3,countBox; 
  private final JButton enterButton; 
  private final JButton clearButton;

  private int count; 
  private String sum; 
  private String inputString, countString; 
  private String sumString; 

  public textBox() 
    { // sets up the components and places them 
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    this.inputLabel = new JLabel("Please enter the vehicle's registration number:"); 
    this.inputBox = new JTextField(8); 
    this.inputLabel2 = new JLabel("Is this a high-value car? Enter yes or no:"); 
    this.inputBox2 = new JTextField(4); 
    this.inputLabel3 = new JLabel("Is this a large vehicle? Enter yes or no:"); 
    this.inputBox3 = new JTextField(4); 
    this.countLabel = new JLabel(" Car Count"); 
    this.countBox = new JTextField(3); 
    this.enterButton = new JButton("Enter"); 
    this.clearButton = new JButton("Clear"); 

    this.add(inputLabel); 
    this.add(inputBox); 
    this.add(inputLabel2); 
    this.add(inputBox2); 
    this.add(inputLabel3); 
    this.add(inputBox3); 
    this.inputBox.addActionListener(this); 
    this.add(countLabel); 
    this.add(countBox); 
    this.countBox.setEditable(false); 


    this.add(enterButton); 
    this.enterButton.addActionListener(this); 
    this.add(clearButton); 
    this.clearButton.addActionListener(this); 
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
      { // reacts to the ENTER key being pressed 
      if (event.getSource() == this.enterButton || event.getSource() == this.inputBox) 
      try 
       { 
       this.inputString = inputBox.getText();  
       this.count += 1; 
       this.countString = Integer.toString(this.count); 
       this.countBox.setText(this.countString); 
       } 

       catch (NumberFormatException entry) 
       { 
         this.inputBox.setText(""); 
       } 
       else if (event.getSource() == this.clearButton) 
       { 
        this.inputBox.setText(""); 
        this.countBox.setText("");  
        this.count = 0; 
        }  
      } 
  }
```

Comment: You need a `List` or a `Map` of registered vehicles and increase the count only when you see a new registration number

Comment: You don't have any listeners attached to the "high-value" or "large-vehicle" text boxes, so are you sure that input in those boxes is causing your problem?  I'd suggest having your `actionPerformed` method log the event (either `event.toString()` or `event.paramString()`); maybe the count is being increased for some events you aren't expecting.  I'm kind of guessing, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a hashmap where the key is the vehicle registration number.
Whenever you find a vehicle registration number which is not present in the hashmap, increment the count. You can even use the hashmap to count the number of times each vehicle registration number is entered.

```
package carpark;


import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.util.HashMap;

public class textBox extends javax.swing.JFrame 
implements ActionListener 
  { // declare the components and variables 
  private final JLabel inputLabel,inputLabel2,inputLabel3,countLabel; 
  private final JTextField inputBox,inputBox2,inputBox3,countBox; 
  private final JButton enterButton; 
  private final JButton clearButton;

  private int count; 
  private String sum; 
  private String inputString, countString; 
  private String sumString; 
  private HashMap<String, Integer> countMap;

  public textBox() 
    { // sets up the components and places them 
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    this.inputLabel = new JLabel("Please enter the vehicle's registration number:"); 
    this.inputBox = new JTextField(8); 
    this.inputLabel2 = new JLabel("Is this a high-value car? Enter yes or no:"); 
    this.inputBox2 = new JTextField(4); 
    this.inputLabel3 = new JLabel("Is this a large vehicle? Enter yes or no:"); 
    this.inputBox3 = new JTextField(4); 
    this.countLabel = new JLabel(" Car Count"); 
    this.countBox = new JTextField(3); 
    this.enterButton = new JButton("Enter"); 
    this.clearButton = new JButton("Clear"); 
    this.countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.add(inputLabel); 
    this.add(inputBox); 
    this.add(inputLabel2); 
    this.add(inputBox2); 
    this.add(inputLabel3); 
    this.add(inputBox3); 
    this.inputBox.addActionListener(this); 
    this.add(countLabel); 
    this.add(countBox); 
    this.countBox.setEditable(false); 


    this.add(enterButton); 
    this.enterButton.addActionListener(this); 
    this.add(clearButton); 
    this.clearButton.addActionListener(this); 
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
      { // reacts to the ENTER key being pressed 
      if (event.getSource() == this.enterButton || event.getSource() == this.inputBox) 
      try 
       { 
       this.inputString = inputBox.getText();  
       //If the hashmap does not contain the key, increment the count and put the registration number as the key into it.
       if(!this.countMap.containsKey(this.inputString)) {
            this.count += 1;
            this.countMap.put(this.inputString, 1);
       }
       //Else you can increment the count in the hashmap.
       this.countString = Integer.toString(this.count); 
       this.countBox.setText(this.countString); 
       } 

       catch (NumberFormatException entry) 
       { 
         this.inputBox.setText(""); 
       } 
       else if (event.getSource() == this.clearButton) 
       { 
        this.inputBox.setText(""); 
        this.countBox.setText("");  
        this.count = 0; 
        }  
      } 
  }
```